# Solving a large system of linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I am very new to Mathematica (started two weeks ago), and I am trying to solve a system of linear equations consisting of nine equation. My matrices `A` and `B` are given below.

```
A = {{I a - I b + c, 0, 0, -I d, -I E^((2 I π)/3) f, 0, -I d, -I f, 0},
 {0, I a + c, 0, -I E^(-((2 I π)/3)) f, -I d, -I E^((2 I π)/3)f, -I f, -I d, -I f}, 
 {0, 0, I a + I b + c,  0, -I E^(-((2 I π)/3)) f, -I d, 0, -I f, -I d},
 {-I d, -I E^((2 I π)/3) f, 0, I a - I b + c, 0, 0, -I d, -I E^(-((2 I π)/3)) f, 0}, 
 {-I E^(-((2 I π)/3)) f, -I d, -I E^((2 I π)/3) f, 0, I a + c, 0, -I E^((2 I π)/3)f, -I d, -I E^(-((2 I π)/3)) f}, 
 {0, -I E^(-((2 I π)/3)) f, -I d, 0, 0, I a + I b + c, 0, -I E^((2 I π)/3) f, -I d}, 
 {-I d, -I f, 0, -I d, -I E^(-((2 I π)/3)) f, 0, I a - I b + c, 0, 0},
 {-I f, -I d, -I f, -I E^((2 I π)/3) f, -I d, -I E^(-((2 I π)/3)) f, 0, I a + c, 0}, 
 {0, -I f, -I d, 0, -I E^((2 I π)/3) f, -I d, 0, 0, I a + I b + c}}

B = {0, I q, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

`I` is iota and other variables are `a, b, c, d, f, q`.

I am using `LinearSolve`, but it is taking forever. How can I solve my system of equations?

Comment: The code is ill-edited it seems. I am trying to make it better but the first line doesn't seems to turn in code. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I have edited your question to improve on the formatting (and the title). Just to be sure: your capital letter [`I`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/I.html) stands for the imaginary unit $i$, right? (I haven't heard it being called by the greek letter iota ...)

Comment: Hi @Domen Yes, I stands for sqrt(-1) and thanks for the editing :)

Comment: Great! How long did you wait for the result? I get the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhJk.png) in approximately a minute in version 13.3.

Comment: What? It was running for six hours and then I stopped it! I am using Mathematica 9.0.1.0.

Comment: @Domen, if it's possible, can you please attach the X vector here? I will ask my organization on how to get it upgraded. I wasted so much time figuring if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried doing it online and getting same result as you with the ...1... thing. But I am not sure how to see the entire result. 'show more' and 'store in notebook' option is not showing full result.

Comment: What do you mean _you tried doing it online_? You have to not that the result is a _very_ large expression (21.5 MB in memory ...).

Comment: "Tried doin online" means using WolframCloud.

Answer (score 1):

All available methods one might use for this give results in  under a minute on my desktop, using version 13.3.

```
Timing[ls1 = LinearSolve[mat, bvec];]
ls1 // LeafCount

(* Out[902]= {43.9821, Null}

Out[903]= 807546 *)

Timing[
 ls2 = LinearSolve[mat, bvec, Method -> "OneStepRowReduction"];]
ls2 // LeafCount

(* Out[904]= {41.8555, Null}

Out[905]= 305563 *)

Timing[
 ls3 = LinearSolve[mat, bvec, Method -> "CofactorExpansion"];]
ls3 // LeafCount

(* Out[906]= {1.22199, Null}

Out[907]= 1333058 *)

Timing[
 ls4 = LinearSolve[mat, bvec, Method -> "DivisionFreeRowReduction"];]
ls4 // LeafCount

(* Out[908]= {44.0486, Null}

Out[909]= 809934 *)
```

It is a bit mysterious why the `Automatic1` setting delivers a result different from all the others. Possibly some heuristic simplification is used. I had thought that setting would just choose `"OneStepRowReduction"` and run with that, but apparently that's not the case.

The (by far) fastest in this case also gives the largest result. But only by a factor of 4 or so vs. the smallest. And we can reduce it substantially in size using `Together`, again in reasonable time.

```
Timing[ls3T = Together[ls3];]
LeafCount[ls3T]

(* Out[914]= {5.94691, Null}

Out[915]= 94294 *)
```

Of course one has to actually do the computations to get the results. (Stated differently, there's no convenient way to predict in advance what method might work best, so we predict after the fact.)